# value not read with redux-persist on app load

Tags: react-native, redux-persist

Iam new to react/react-native and was trying react-native application. My idea is to set a client_id that persists on app start, restart, uninstall, and installs.

So when i try saving from editor (ctrl+s), I can see the client is persisted and same. When I close the app and re-launch, the client id changes (done from mobile or refresh r from the node/js server). but when i save (ctrl+s) without any code changes, the client id reverts to initial id that was generated first (first dispatch action). So I understand that value is persisted but app is not reading from persisted store and that is why it is showing different number on every launch (or refresh from node/js server window.) But how to ensure value from store is read on launch/re-launch.

Can some one help me resolve this ? I am trying from last few days. Thanks in advance.
Here is my code.

```
// clientstore.js
const persistConfig = {
    key: 'root',
    storage: AsyncStorage,
    stateReconciler: hardSet,
};

export default function getStore() {
    const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, storeReducer);
    let store = createStore(persistedReducer);
    let persistor = persistStore(store);
    return { store, persistor };
}

// storereducer.js

const defaultState = {
    client_id: ''
}

const storeReducer = (state = defaultState, action = {}) => {
    const { type, payload } = action;
    var tmp_object = Object.assign({}, state);
    switch (type) {
        case 'SET_CLIENTID':
            tmp_object.client_id = state.client_id.toString()=='' ? payload : state.client_id;
            return tmp_object;
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

//App.js
const { store, persistor } = getStore();
persistor.persist(); // adding or removing makes no difference
const App = () => {
    if (store.getState().client_id.toString()=='') {
      store.dispatch({type: 'SET_CLIENTID', payload: genTerrierToken()});
      persistor.flush(); //adding or removing makes no difference
    }
    return (
        <View><Text>
            Client ID: {store.getState().client_id}
        </Text></View>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally, i could solve this :) I got the spark from https://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/presentations/workshops/redux-fundamentals/react-redux.html#/1

and i changed the App.js to

```
const { store, persistor } = getStore();

const App = () => {
    if (store.getState().client_id.toString()=='') {
      store.dispatch({type: 'SET_CLIENTID', payload: genTerrierToken()});
    }
    return (
        <View><Text>
            Client ID: {store.getState().client_id}
        </Text></View>
    );
}

export default () => {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <PersistGate loading={<ActivityIndicator />} persistor={persistor}>
        <App />
      </PersistGate>
    </Provider>
  );
}
```

Now every thing works the perfect way.